# Angular 2 (4) What's the way to manage response for multiple async calls

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, loopback, angular-loopback

I have a simple question, how I can manage response for simultaneous async calls?

Explain: I have a loop of array json with typescript, and I call a Loopback Api in each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    this.dataApi.patchOrCreate(data[i]).subscribe((resp: any)=> {
        console.log(resp);
    }, (err: any)=>{
        console.log('ERR',err);
    });
}
```

The problem is in the response for each call. I want to close modal if all responses are ok. How can I do that?

I tried to use `Observable.forkJoin` but the problem was the number of calls are dynamic:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.dataApi.patchOrCreate(data[0]),
    this.dataApi.patchOrCreate(data[1]),
    this.dataApi.patchOrCreate(data[2]),
).subscribe(result => {
    //Close modal
    console.log('response',result[0],result[1]);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array field, then push the observables while looping. And then use this field inside the `forkJoin`

```
myObservables = [];

constructor(...)
...

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    this.myObservables.push(this.dataApi.patchOrCreate(data[i]));
}
...
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.myObservables
).subscribe(result => {
    //Close modal
    console.log('response',result[0],result[1]);
});
```